Gitlab CronJob - Every day but Wed?
I want to verify that im writing this correctly, crontab.guru says it isn't standard and may not work on every system.
What im trying to do is run a test pipeline every day except on wednesday.
From what I put in it should like like this:
0 2 * * Mon,Tue,Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun (Should be 2:00am everyday but Wed).
Is this correct?

Gitlab cron use standard cron definition
# ┌───────────── minute (0 - 59)
# │ ┌───────────── hour (0 - 23)
# │ │ ┌───────────── day of the month (1 - 31)
# │ │ │ ┌───────────── month (1 - 12)
# │ │ │ │ ┌───────────── day of the week (0 - 6) (Sunday to Saturday)
# │ │ │ │ │
# │ │ │ │ │
# │ │ │ │ │
# * * * * * <command to execute>

then your setup should be
0 2 * * 0,1,2,4,5,6

0 2 : at 02:00
* * : every day of the month & every month
0,1,2,4,5,6 : every day of the week except 3 (wednesday)
Link crontab.guru with this configuration.

This is OK. It should be accepted on some cron implementation. What you can try is to replace name of the week days with numbers:
0 2 * * 1,2,4,5,6,7 <command>

P.S. Seems GitLab use some strange cron format and Sunday is 0 (not 0 or 7as it is in UNIX/Linux). So the command should be:
0 2 * * 0,1,2,4,5,6 <command>

